# Brute force on several BackgroundWorkers faster?

Tags: c#, cpu, backgroundworker, brute-force

My C# Brute Force programm uses 20% of CPU in runtime. Im only using 1 Backgroundworker for it. If I would spread this task into several parts and insert them in 7-8 Backgroundworkers, would that be faster and use more CPU?

Comment: Did you tried ?

Comment: Not yet. But maybe anyone of you can give me an answer before im trying.

Comment: @AxelKemper not necessarily, that 20% CPU usage could easily be the entirety of a single core...

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is maybe.

The long answer is that it depends upon multiple factors:

1. Is your task CPU bound, if it's not the CPU holding up the task then multithreading probably won't help.
2. How many cores does your processor have and does it have hyperthreading enabled: if it only has one thread, trying to multithread will actually slow it down; if it has more, you can use as many threads in your program as you have available in the OS. (I suggest that you use the `Environment.ProcessorCount` value to determine the number of threads that you start).
3. How much cross-thread synchronisation will have to occur. If your threads are spending ages waiting to write into locked shared variables or passing data between them, it will likely slow your application down.

My main suggestion would be to test it!

You can easily time the execution time of a segment of code fairly accurately using the intuitive `Stopwatch` class.

Finally, you might want to try using a `Thread[]` rather than background workers, in general, these have lower overheads so are slightly quicker.

Comment: Using a profiler, e.g. ANTS Performance Profiler or the VS-built-in one also helps understanding performance.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the word "stack". One time with only 1 Backgroundworker the second time with 5. Backgroundworker 1 searches for a word with the length of 1. background worker 2 for a word with the length of 2 and so on.

```
Word: stack
Backgroundworker    Time
1                   1min 8sec
5                   35sec
```